# How to add Tailwind CSS with Quasar?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to integrate Tailwind CSS in the latest Quasar version (3.5.4)

I have installed Tailwind CSS using `npm install tailwindcss`
and after that I have added `require('tailwind')` in `.postcssrc.js` but it results in an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config') tailwind typescript

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Harris' answer but with a separate `.css` file. Follow these steps:

**1)** `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

**2)** `npx tailwindcss init`

**3)** Configure your template paths at `tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**4)** Create a file at `src/css/tailwind.css` and add the Tailwind directives:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

**5)** Modify the `postcss.config.js` file (require tailwindcss)

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer
    require('autoprefixer')({
      overrideBrowserslist: [
        'last 4 Chrome versions',
        'last 4 Firefox versions',
        'last 4 Edge versions',
        'last 4 Safari versions',
        'last 4 Android versions',
        'last 4 ChromeAndroid versions',
        'last 4 FirefoxAndroid versions',
        'last 4 iOS versions'
      ]
    }),
    require('tailwindcss') // add this
  ]
}
```

**6)** Finally, we include the `tailwind.css` in `quasar.config.js` (css option)

```js
...
css: [
      'app.scss',
      'tailwind.css'
],
...
```

Also, I recommend adding a prefix to all tailwind classes since Quasar has also some utilities classes that overwrites the tailwind ones.
Adding this option to `tailwind.config.js` solves the problem:

```js
prefix: 'tw-'
```

Comment: Is this still the best approach to using tailwind css with quasar? No answer was ever selected.

Comment: @IrishRedneck YES

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Quasar project and run:

```
run npm i -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7autoprefixer@^9
```

Then go to `.postcssrc.js` and add:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // to edit target browsers: use "browserslist" field in package.json
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('tailwindcss')

  ],
}
```

Then in any Vue.js component add this in the style tag import:

```
<style>
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
</style>
```